# How To find out what is hiding/acting on a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I have a simple `<a>` tag that is getting hidden from some JS. (`display:none`)
I have looked into the page source and I can see it is not hidden, however the inspector shows it as display:none ( inline style )

No result finding out the class/id in JS code in order to isolate the part of the code that is hiding the `<a>`.

Is there a tool or fixed procedure that can help me to debug this?

Comment: why down vote ? should I edit/mod my question in some way ?

Comment: Try using breakpoints in firebug/chrome dev tools. Step through the code line by line and you'll be able to identify the line where the hiding is happening.

Comment: Are you sure it is hidden by JS and not CSS?

Comment: Maybe you can share a link? Or code?

Comment: Can you explain what hidden means ? Is it `display:none`, `visibility:hidden` or its removed from DOM ? Is it happening on this <a> elem or on its parent?

Comment: `display:none` ... I have added more info above

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Chrome lets you break code when an attribute on an element is changed.

1. Open the developer tools using F12, and select the "Elements" tab. Find the element that gets hidden. Right click on it, "Break on", "Attributes Modification".
2. Refresh the page, keeping Developer Tools open.

If the element is being hidden using JavaScript, you'll break at that point.

Otherwise, it's done via CSS. If this is the case, using the "Elements" tab again, select the element you're interested in and look at the "Styles" applied to it in the right hand column. Chrome will show which styles are applied by which definition in which stylesheet. It should then be trivial to find the one hiding the element.

> [image]

Comment: Just crosschecked: disabling JS remove the hidden property so now I'm sure it is JS related. however the above trick doesn't work ( same on FF )

Comment: @Francesco: It works for me... are you sure the element isn't getting *replaced* with a similar element, rather than updated? Are you leaving Chrome tools open when you refresh? Are you sure you're targeting the right element? Without giving a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or a link to the page you're having problems with, it's hard to help you further.

Comment: did some 'manual' debug :( `$('...').find('a').eq(1).css({'display':'none'});`

Comment: Even if it was not working for me I think your approach is the best, but take care it doesn't work always

Comment: The system passes by all JavaScript files that jQuery is associated. It takes long to get to the file and the line that is actually modifying the element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, look if it is hidden from inline style or by a css class.

Then, if is by a css class, search in all your project for that class (you should find a javascript function that adds this class to the element).

If is hidden by inline style property, look inside your project for any `.style.display =` property.

If you are using jquery try like this:

```
// Search by class
.addClass(".hiddenClass

// Search by css
.hide(), or $(".elementSelector").hide()
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with the question: "Is there a tool or fixed procedure that can help me to debug this?"

Comment: This would be the procedure i would follow if i face the same issue like Francesco has.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure that it is indeed javascript that hides your element, as it could easily be css. The easiest first step is to check the element and see if by any chance its default css is hiding it.

Second. Is your js code in one file or do you import multiple js files in your page? 
If you have multiple js files you could try.

Import 1 file
then use javascript to Show your element
then import the rest of the files.

If the code that hides your element is located in the first file then your element will be visible (because you made it visible after hiding it first)
if the element is not visible it means that the hiding takes place in a subsequent file.
Move your javascript code showing the element after the second import and so on...

Last but not least make sure your code does not import external css files as well.

I recommend using Chrome Dev Tools for any javascript debugging you do.

Comment: I think Matt's answer is spot on for this question. Regardless, I will not delete the answer because it provides an alternative.